# Как в Unit тестах сравнивать значения внутри объектов?

Tags: android, kotlin, объекты, junit, equals

Есть Unit тест:

```
class ExchangeRateUseCaseTest {
  
    val userRepository = mock<ExchangeRateCall>()
  
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
  
    @Test
    fun loadExchangeRate() {
  
        val testLiveData = listOf<ExchangeRateModel>(ExchangeRateModel(0, "name", 0.34), ExchangeRateModel(1, "name2", 0.35))
  
        val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>()
        liveData.value = testLiveData
        Mockito.`when`(userRepository.loadCurrency()).thenReturn(liveData)
  
        val useCase = ExchangeRateUseCase(userRepository)
        val actual = useCase.loadExchangeRate()
  
        val liveData2 = MutableLiveData<List<ExchangeRateModel>>()
        liveData2.value = listOf<ExchangeRateModel>(ExchangeRateModel(0, "name", 0.34), ExchangeRateModel(1, "name2", 0.35))
  
        Assert.assertEquals(liveData2, actual)
  
    }
}
```

При запуске предсказуемо (так как происходит сравнение объектов) вылетает следующее:

```
expected:<androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@49bf29c6> but was:<androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@7ee55e70>
Expected :androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@49bf29c6
Actual   :androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@7ee55e70
<Click to see difference>

java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@49bf29c6> but was:<androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData@7ee55e70>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
    at com.sem.exchangerate.domain.useCase.ExchangeRateUseCaseTest.loadExchangeRate(ExchangeRateUseCaseTest.kt:36)
```

Можно, конечно сделать так:

```
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(0).id, actual.value!!.get(0).id)
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(0).name, actual.value!!.get(0).name)
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(0).exchange, actual.value!!.get(0).exchange)
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(1).id, actual.value!!.get(1).id)
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(1).name, actual.value!!.get(1).name)
Assert.assertEquals(liveData2.value!!.get(1).exchange, actual.value!!.get(1).exchange)
```

и тогда всё будет работать корректно, но решение получается каким-то уж слишком громоздким.

Есть ли способ сделать сравнение более коротким, но чтобы при этом сравнивались именно значения внутри объектов, а не сами объекты?

Comment: а кроме junit что-то другое можно использовать?

Comment: у `ExchangeRateModel` есть `equals`, который правильно (т.е. по полям) сравнивает объекты?

Comment: Так же как и не в тестах: у объектов должен быть переопределён метод `equals()` и  в нём реализовано сравнение содержимого как душе угодно.

Comment: @MrFylypenko, с чем-то другим я пока что не работал, поэтому желательно для junit

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA, нету